# Install elementary OS on ASUS T100TA

Tags: system-installation, uefi, asus

I have a tablet with keyboard (2 in 1) Asus T100TA with 32 GB SSD and 32 GB SD card, actually with Windows 10.

But I would like install and use elementary OS, but flash disk and DVD not booting.

Apparently, it can have a problem with WiFi and I wonder if it is possible to somehow install elementary OS on this tablet and have it fully operational.